# Slideshow with javascript without absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow

I need something like this
http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow

but w/o the absolute positioning.
Is it possible?

If not, how do I deal with the absolute positioning - if I make it centered for one screen res, it won't be for another. Any tips?

Comment: Why do you think you need absolute positioning to center an element?

Comment: you didn't understand me - absolute positioning is used in virtually every slideshow. But it makes it tricky to deal with the page layout - because it's well..absolute. Hence my question, how do implement the slideshow w/o absolute positioning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you need to place on image on top of another you can do it in one of two ways:

1) Use absolute positioning

The slideshow should be contained within a wrapper element that has `position:relative`, then the contents of the slideshow use `position:absolute`. The layout will not be affected because the "absolute" elements are within, and relative to, the wrapper, *not the rest of the page*.

2) Use one image on top of an element that has a background image

You can make a slideshow easily this way:

- Set the background image to the first frame
- Fade-in the image (the second frame) which is on top of the background
- Set the background to the same image as the second frame
- Hide the second frame
- Swap the SRC of the second frame to the third image
- Repeat

Comment: great answer,  i went with the option 1. You answered exactly what i asked! I didn't realize that absolute is not absolute to the left corner of the screen but to the wrapping element. Thanks much!

Comment: It it relative to the first parent that has "position:relative", which COULD be the page if there is no parent with this property.